# How can I write a PrimitiveSequence extension include <T: Codable>

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, moya

I writing Network Layer with Moya and `RxSwift`, server response JSON like this:

```
{ "code": 200, "msg": "", data: {}}
```

I want return data only on success with code eques 200, return error if code not equal 200, what should I do?

I try to write code like this

```
extension PrimitiveSequence where TraitType == SingleTrait, ElementType == BaseBean<T: Codable>
```

this is code of response object:

```
struct BaseBean<T: Codable> : Codable {
    let code: Int
    let msg: String
    let data: T?

    func map() throws -> T {
        if code != 200 {
            throw ApiError(reason: msg)
        }
        if data == nil {
            throw ApiError(reason: "Empty Data")
        }
        return data!
    }
}
```

I expect the call method like this

```
  static func userInfo(params: UserInfoParams) -> Single<UserInfo> {
        return provider.rx.request(.userInfo(params: params)).map(BaseBean<UserInfo>).map()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead.

```
func userInfo(params: UserInfoParams) -> Single<UserInfo> {
    return provider.rx.request(.userInfo(params: params))
        .map(BaseBean<UserInfo>)
        .map { $0.map() }
    }
```

I don't think you should name your function `map()`, better would be something like `validatedData()`.